# How to connect oracle database docker image

Tags: docker, oracle

I have registered with the docker image of oracle database and got below link to pull the image.

```
docker pull store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1
```

No other tags available to see on the page. But some how I got information about 12.1.0.2

With 12.2.0.1, I am able to run a database and connect to it.
But with 12.1.0.2, the database is not connecting.

```
docker service create --with-registry-auth --network=oracle_net --name Oracledb_39 -p target=1521 store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1
```

The above container is working but if I trey with below tag, the database is not connecting.

```
docker service create --with-registry-auth --network=oracle_net --name Oracledb_39 -p target=1521 store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.1.0.2
```

The 12.1.0.2 with dbeaver client to connect:

[connectivity with 12.1.0.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKhL0.png)

But able to connect with 12.2.0.1

[connectivity with 12.2.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5atM.png)

Please suggest how to connect to 12.1.0.2 or any of 12.1.x

And also please share how to see all the tags available for oracle database docker image.

I have deployed it in swarm to test, same result with direct docker run also.

```
docker exec -it Oracledb_38.1.k3who8un6hs9vulwljwvhx4x4 sqlplus sys@ORCLCDB
```

Inside container:

```
[root@bf9581972c5a /]# ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 12:07 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /home/oracle/setup/dockerInit.sh
root        34     1  0 12:09 ?        00:00:00 tail -f /home/oracle/setup/log/dockerInit.log
root        40     0  0 19:09 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
root        60    40  0 19:10 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef

[root@bf9581972c5a /]# sqlplus
bash: sqlplus: command not found
```

The container logs:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-47-251 ~]$ docker logs Oracledb_38.1.k3who8un6hs9vulwljwvhx4x4
User check : root.
Setup Oracle Database
Oracle Database 12.1.0.2 Setup
Tue Aug 3 12:07:09 UTC 2021

Check parameters ......
log file is : /home/oracle/setup/log/paramChk.log
paramChk.sh is done at 0 sec

untar DB bits ......
log file is : /home/oracle/setup/log/untarDB.log
untarDB.sh is done at 153 sec

config DB ......
log file is : /home/oracle/setup/log/configDB.log
grep: /home/oracle/setup/log/configDBora.log: No such file or directory
configDB.sh is done at 153 sec

Done ! The database is ready for use .
Tue Aug 3 12:07:09 UTC 2021
User check : root.
Setup Oracle Database
```

The container is in running state only, but not able to connect to it when I tried with dbeaver or any other oracle client applications.

Answer (score 1):

You better check whether DB is running at all by checking your container status.

This link has a lot of information about Oracle in container (credits to [chuck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6388400/chuck) and his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45556996/520567)).

https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/b/weblog/archive/2017/06/21/modularization-by-using-oracle-database-containers-and-pdbs-on-docker-engine

wrt tags, seems like this is an old image, check `docker inspect ...` to see when it was produced. You may see other tags as well.

For a newer version you can check instructions how to build by yourself at:
https://github.com/3scale/oracle-database

Update: link to more official instructions for building Oracle images https://github.com/oracle/docker-images

Comment: I added details can you please check the new data

Comment: @SaraJune, I'm not an oracle expert. But it looks like images you are using are rather old. Better go with the newer images I gave you a link to. Or directly check https://github.com/oracle/docker-images . Or use `12.2.0.1` which in store is listed as the latest. Even though `12.2.0.2` tag exists, it doesn't mean it worked for anybody.

Comment: We need 12.1.0.2, old version. To support a specific customer. 12.2.0.1 is working.But we need 12.1.0.2, not 12.2.0.2

Comment: Even I tried buiding custom images from the link you shared.But it seems, the credentials are not working for that and getting same error. Even passed as env variables while creating container